# Psexec, Web Service, IIS issue

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, psexec, dhcp

I create a Web Service that will run a Psexec to execute a command to DHCP server *(netsh dhcp server **DHCP-IP-address** show scope)*.
It is running **perfectly** when I test/run it via Visual Studio in the IIS server.

**BUT**
When I deploy the Web Service to the IIS, it does not work right/properly.
The Web Service does not have any return result of the command *(netsh dhcp server **DHCP-IP-address** show scope)*.

How to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main sources of failure here could be that the ThreadPool identity on the IIS server may not have the permissions required to psexec over to the DHCP server.  When you are running on your own machine (under Visual Studio) the psexec is initiated under your identity.  When IIS runs it on the server, it's under the thread pool identity.

Comment: Thank you DWright for your response.

I don't have also access to the DHCP Server.
I am using a application account to run the command that has access to the DHCP server.